# Can the NPM registry be removed from package-lock.json file?

Tags: npm, package.json

I work behind a corporate Firewall, So I have to set a registry in `npm` like

`npm config set registry https://aa-artifactory.abc.com/artifactory/api/npm-repo/`

I have now finished building my app and want to deploy on Heroku. However when I try to deploy, the build fails & the below error is shown

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
       npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
       npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
       npm ERR! network request to https://aa-artifactory.abc.com/artifactory/api/npm-repo/yargs-parser/-/yargs-parser-20.2.9.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND aa-artifactory.abc.com
       npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
       npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
       npm ERR! network 
       npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
       npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I think is a natural error since Heroku will not have access to the registry of the company.

I tried to find from where the registry info is being sent & it turns out it is in `package-lock.json`. I was not aware why we even have `package-lock.json`!.

Every dependency(even the "indirect" dependencies) has an entry like below & you can see the `resolved` key with the registry info.

```
"node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer": {
      "version": "1.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://aa-artifactory.abc.com/artifactory/api/npm-repo/@szmarczak/http-timer/-/http-timer-1.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-sWZeLEYaLNkvTBu/UNVFTeDUtCE=",
      "dev": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "defer-to-connect": "^1.0.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6"
      }
    }
```

Now, the question is, how can I deploy my app on Heroku.

- Should I just remove `package-lock.json` & just use `package.json`? Will this work?
- Or should i just modify the `package-lock.json` file? This seems tedious but may be worthwhile if i want to control the exact version of packages.

Please guide.

Comment: If you are deploying on Heroku there you can add your npm command in the setting there is an options button in there you can add this and try maybe it could work for you! because I had before those error when I was deploying my nodejs on Heroku

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your suggestion. I do have the npm build command in my `package.json.com` & that is what is generating this error. Have I missed something?

Comment: Is your repository publicly visible? because I will need to have a look at the package.jason file I checked in my project where I have deployed on Heroku.